# Official tutorial codes appearing red wave line in Eclipse not allowing me to compile

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am a beginner in Android programming. I was going through the official tutorial on Android developer site. When I copied the codes for the Grid View tutorial to Eclipse, many red wave underlines appeared which are not allowing me to compile. Every time I click the run button, it says "Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application."

I am using a WIN7 and followed every single step that is necessary for setting up the envrionment. I had no problem at with previous tutorials such as Hello Android, Linear Layout, Relative Layout, and Table View.

Does anyone have the same experience and have a solution for this? I have tried to clean and re-build the project, which doesn't help.

Comment: out of the blue no ideas, maybe you could add what type of errors you are getting, which lines of code etc.

Comment: kindly hover the mouse over the red sign and tell us what the error (s) is/are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be helpful to provide a link to the gridview tutorial you speak of. I'll assume you meant this one: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

First things first: Did you download the sample art? Did you put it in res/drawable?

What errors were you getting?

Comment: The page is at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Comment: Some of the errors are: Syntax error on token "void", @ expected/Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)/BaseAdapter cannot be resolved to a type/Context cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Yes, I did download the sample art and put it in the res/drawable

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you are working in an Android project and not a standard Java project?

Comment: I remember I created an Android project.

Comment: I did exactly what told on the tutorial page.

Comment: It might be that your imports are broken.  Hard to see.

Comment: No, that you didn't copy the import statement part of the original source.  Do you have a more experienced programmer or teacher you can ask in person?